# Uploaded 'server' Folder Appears Empty on GitHub Despite Local Functionality

Tags: github, repository, github-for-windows, .git-folder

To provide some context, I initially included the 'server' folder after the repository was established. Locally, it integrates seamlessly with the rest of the project and operates without any hitches. However, when the repository is pushed to GitHub, the contents of the 'server' module seem to vanish, and I'm unable to inspect its inner workings on the GitHub platform.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into potential solutions, I'd be greatly appreciative of any assistance. Thank you in advance for your expertise."

[image]